# Regex to validate initials

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to validate initials. The only format I want it to allow is:

(a capital followed by a period), and that one or more times

Valid examples:

A.
A.B.
A.B.C.

Invalid examples:

a.
a
A
A B
A B C
AB
ABC

Using The Regulator and some websites I have found the following regex, but it only allows exactly one upper (or lower!) case character followed by a period:

```
^[A-Z][/.]$
```

Basically I only need to know how to force upper case characters, and how I can repeat the validation to allow more the one occurence of an upper case character followed by a period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost has it right: `+` says "one or more occurenses" and it's `\.`, not `/.`

Wrapping it in `()` denotes that it's a group.

```
^([A-Z]\.)+$
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change your regex a bit in order to make it work in my system:
^([A-Z][/.])+$

Comment: I'd recommend adding ?: to the beginning of the group like this: `^(?:[A-Z]\.)+$`. This would not capture this group.

Comment: It depends on how it should be used. If he just wants to see if it matches then it's reason to capture the group.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick regular expression lesson:

- `a` matches exactly one `a`
- `a+` matches one or more `a` in a row
- `ab` matches `a` followed by `b`
- `ab+` matches `a` followed by one or more `b` in a row
- `(ab)+` matches one or more of `a` followed by `b`

So in this case, something like this should work:

```
^([A-Z][.])+$
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.com/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

---

#### Variations

You can also use something like this:

```
^(?:[A-Z]\.)+$
```

The `(?:pattern)` is a non-capturing group. The `\.` is how you match a literal `.`, because otherwise it's a metacharacter that means "(almost) any character".

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

---

#### Even more variations

Since you said you're matching initials, you may want to impose some restriction on what is a reasonable number of repetition.

A limited repetition syntax in regex is something like this:

```
^(?:[A-Z]\.){1,10}$
```

This will match at least one, but only up to 10 letters and period repetition ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/ji5xxVSmWh)).

Comment: . matches any character. You need to escape it: ^([A-Z][\.])+$. And it's not necessary to put the dot in brackets as it's only only one character

Comment: @simen: You don't need to escape `.` inside a character class definition. `[.]` is a character class definition that matches only one character, the period. I sometimes prefer `[.]` to `\.` (or `\\.` in string literals of some languages) but that's just me.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Ah, makes sense. \. has always served me well though :)

Comment: the nice thing about [.] is you don't have to worry about escaping (how many slashes to use in which context)

Comment: @seanizer: yep, and one would hope at least that if `\.` is significantly faster than `[.]`, then a decent regex engine would optimize the latter to the former.

Comment: Thanks. I have given the first answer the label "accepted answer" already, but your answer is helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

the regex you want is this:

```
^(?:[A-Z]\.)+$
```

the ?: marks the group as non-captured

case sensitivity is however a flag which is handled differently in every language. but in most implementations it is active by default

Comment: He wrote "case sensitivity (...) is active by default". However, in many editors with regex support, it's the other way around.

Comment: I was talking about languages, not editors. I'm pretty sure that java, javascript, php and perl have case sensitivity turned on by default

Comment: yes, I as commented: I mis-read your answer. I thought you meant that case-insensitive was enabled by default. I haven't drank enough coffee, I guess...